# How to change the position of the vector arrow and the dot?

Tags: pdftex, positioning, unicode-math, vector

The unicode-math package makes the positioning of the vector arrow created by \vec{} and the dot of \dot{} nicer but the package is not compatible with pdflatex. Without unicode-math, the arrow is slightly misplaced to the right and unneccessarily italicized and the dot is smaller and slightly misplaced to the left.

[image: \vec and \dot with and without unicode-math]

My question is how can I change the position and styling of the vector arrow and the dot if I have to compile with pdflatex?

I compiled this with XeLaTeX to produce (1):

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

with unicode-math:
\begin{equation}
    \Huge \dot{\vec{\psi}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I compiled this with pdflatex to produce (2):

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

without unicode-math:
\begin{equation}
    \Huge \dot{\vec{\psi}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Add `\usepackage{amsmath}` to the preamble of your document.

Comment: it always helps if you show a complete small document, it is hard to debug an image and the positioning depends on the packages and fonts  you are using.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for your answer. I tried it and it makes the result even worse :) I tried it locally on my machine and on Overleaf too, with the same result. [link](https://imgur.com/a/P8vmBAy)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are absolutely right. I added the source code of the examples to my question.

Comment: You ignore all the warnings for putting `\Huge` inside an equation. So what do you expect?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I didn't checked the warnings at all because the output was what I expected from `\Huge`: an equation in a large font size. And besides that the original question wasn't related to the fontsize. I just wanted to create a minimal example and an image to attach it to the question.

Comment: All I wanted to say in my above comment is that when I compile `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \dot{\vec{\psi}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}`, I reproduce the issue, if I add `\usepackage{amsmath}` to the preamble, the issue is gone. Now, if you add something that triggers multiple warnings I find it not too surprising that the output has issues. It is just not correct to add `\Huge` inside an equation, and if you do it nonetheless, LaTeX cannot do much more than to issue a warning or error message.

Comment: any size change in math will lead to inconsistent results, it may sometimes make some symbols be larger but not always and the spacing may be completely wrong. the font size should be before the equation (which is what I did in the answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact position depends on the fonts used, and you showed no code. You can add spacing to offset the accent to change the positioning if you prefer. With the default computer modern fonts you get the first example below, where the spacing is not as bad as in the image you showed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\dot{\vec{\psi}}$


$\dot{\vec{\!\psi}\,}$
\end{document}
```

or with `\Huge` added to match the example that has been added to the question

[image]

double accents are much improved using `amsmath` although as shown here it is still possible to add further offsets to help with tricky combinations.

Comment: In other words the answer is simply to add and remove horizontal space manually. I have to apply this only to ψ and only two times in my article so it is a completely acceptable solution. Thank you.